# Highcharts: Stacking a column inside of another column

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I don't know if highchart has support for this, I can't seem to find anything in my searched. But I would like to stack a column inside a column.

I have 2 series of data: Daily Active Users (DAU), and New Users (NU). New Users is a part of Daily Active Users therefore I would like to stack New Users inside of Daily Active Users, not on top of it.

Example: For one entry New Users is 3, and Daily Active Users 10. On the Y axis, I would like to have Daily Active Users reach to value 10, but I would want to start plotting New Users at value 7.

Here is what I have so far. This is incorrect because New Users is just plotted on top of Daily Active Users.

http://jsfiddle.net/6JACr/1/

If you look at the first entry of August 6th, 2013: Daily Active Users is 6,310 and New Users is 1,325. New Users is being plotted starting at 6,310 when I want it to be starting at 4,985 (6,310-1,325).

Here is the code where I stack the columns

```
nu_series = {
        name: "NU",
        type: "column",
        data: nu_data,
        stack: 0
};
all_series[1] = nu_series;
dau_series = {
        name: "DAU",
        type: "column",
        data: dau_data,
        stack: 0
};
all_series[2] = dau_series;
```

Comment: Your ajax call in your fiddle is failing.  It might be better to use some dummy data instead of depending on your server.

Comment: Your ajax call seems to fail. Probably due to it being your staging server and probably not accessible to us... only you. It returns this errorMsg: "ip_error"

Comment: sorry ill get on that now

Answer (score 3):

[This Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/column-grouping-false/)

This what your looking for? Basically turn off grouping and stacking and transparent colors

$(function () {

```
    // First, let's make the colors transparent
    Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
        return Highcharts.Color(color)
            .setOpacity(0.5)
            .get('rgba');
    });

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 100,
            y: 70,
            floating: true,
            shadow: true
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: ' mm'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                grouping: false,
                shadow: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            pointPadding: 0

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3],
            pointPadding: 0.1

        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2],
            pointPadding: 0.2

        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1],
            pointPadding: 0.3

        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: This isn't exactly the answer I am looking for, although it is close and accomplishes essentially the same task. In your answer, the inner columns start from the bottom, but I would like them instead to start closer to the top and end where the outter column ends. For example: In my fiddle, for the first column entry, I would like DAU to take up the yAxis values from [0,6,130] and I would like NU to take up yAxis values from [4,985, 6,130]